# How to override JXBrowser default downloads file path?

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

I am trying to figure out that any property exists at JX Browser level to provide default downloads path location for files/images. I see that we have `setPopupHandler` and `setDownloadHandler` in Java side but just wanted to know any property exists at JX Browser level so that end user can have a choice to change at anytime like google chrome Settings -> Advanced -> Downloads -> Location

Comment: *"I see that we have .. in Java side"* You can offer the user a menu item to set it themselves. To make it user friendly, offer a `JFileChooser` to prompt for a directory.

Comment: That is the one option we have but just wanted to know that any property exists at JX Browser end.

Answer (score 1):

To override the default downloads file path, you'll need to get the filename of it, then create a new file with your custom file path + filename.
In the final, set the default destination file to that file. Like this.

```
            browser.setDownloadHandler(new DownloadHandler() {
                public boolean allowDownload(DownloadItem download) {
                    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(download.getDestinationFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    //String ext = "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(download.getDestinationFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    String destination = "C:\\yourPath\\downloadLocation\\";
                    File file = new File(destination + fileName);
                    download.setDestinationFile(file);
                    
                    download.addDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                        public void onDownloadUpdated(DownloadEvent event) {
                            DownloadItem download = event.getDownloadItem();

                            if (download.isCompleted()) {
                                System.out.println("Download is completed!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    System.out.println("Dest file: " + download.getDestinationFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    return true;
                }
            });
```